# Converting Linux partition to primary partition

Tags: linux, partitioning

I have installed Linux. How can i convert partitions created by linux to primary partition?
Here is the diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:               Windows_NTFS Windows                 83.9 GB    disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS mac                     89.3 GB    disk0s2
   3:                      Linux                         524.3 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Linux_LVM                         76.4 GB    disk0s5
```

disk0s1: windows boot loader
disk0s2: chameleon bootloader (active)

Problem is that I have installed linux with option "Install bootloader to /dev/sda" unchecked. Now i cannot boot into linux. Chameleon bootloader just gives me windows and mac options. I think Linux/Linux_LVM paritions are not primary thats y they are not showing in chameleon menu.

Comment: .​.​. W​h​a​t​?

Comment: You need to give more information to get a helpful answer. This may or may not be possible depending on how many partitions you have. Describe your current and desired partition setup, including at least the list of operating systems you have on this particular disk, the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` (or `/dev/sdb`, or `/dev/hda`, or...) under Linux, and information about your bootloader and what operating system(s) you boot with it. There are also very few circumstances in which it would be useful, so if you explain why you want to do it, maybe people can suggest alternatives.

Comment: I have updated the question.